# Local branch behind remote branch (pull, rebase, fetch, merge)

Tags: git, github, branch

If I am working on my branch, `branch1` and then I push some commits while my team member was also working on `branch1`--when it comes time for my team member to push his changes, he's now behind.

What is the easiest way for him to get my most recent commits, and attempt to merge his changes with mine? Let's assume he has already committed his changes before realizing this error.

I thought you'd do:

`git pull origin/branch1 && git merge origin/branch1`

but that doesn't seem to work at all.

I believe you'd do a `rebase`, but I'm unsure of the process; all anyone talks about is doing `rebase` with `master`--but I don't want to do anything with `master` at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `git pull origin/branch1 && git merge origin/branch1`

#### `git pull`

`git pull` is actually an alias to those 2 commands: `git fetch + git merge` so your second part of the command is useless.

---

#### The way to grab changes is this - Several option:

```
# Update your local repo with the latest code:
git fetch --all --prune

# Merge the changes (you already did a pull)
git merge origin branch1
```

OR:

```
# grab & merge the latest changes into your current branch 
git pull origin branch1
```

---

#### `rebase`

If you want your changes to be on top of the other changes then you can use the `--rebase` flag when pulling the content.

```
# As before - update your local repo with the latest code:
git fetch --all --prune

# Merge the changes with the rebase flag
git pull --rebase origin/branch1
```

[image]

Image src: http://blogs.atlassian.com/

---

#### Stash + rebase automatically

You have those config  which you can set:

`rebase.autoStash` + `pull.rebase`

> #### `rebase.autoStash`
>
> When set to true, **automatically create a temporary stash** before the operation begins, and apply it after the operation ends.
>   This means that you can run `rebase` on a dirty `worktree`.
>
> However, use with care: the final stash application after a successful `rebase` might result in non-trivial conflicts. Defaults to false.
>
> #### `pull.rebase`
>
> When true, rebase branches on top of the fetched branch, instead of merging the default branch from the default remote when "git pull" is run.

```
git config pull.rebase true
git config rebase.autoStash true
```