# git push to heroku was rejected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github

I have been trying to push my app to heroku using **git push heroku master**

but I  keep getting this error message. what should I do?

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/raad-photo-app.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

[Related Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMZBq.jpg)

Comment: First, you follow the advised that git give you?

Answer (score 2):

You must pull latest changes from the remote before you can push.

Someone added new code which you don't have locally do you must grab it first.

Read this question to understand what is pull and why do you need it.
[Local branch behind remote branch (pull, rebase, fetch, merge)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35355879/local-branch-behind-remote-branch-pull-rebase-fetch-merge/35356334#35356334)